# About Countable Support iteration of Proper forcing notions and CH

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Assume $CH$. $P$ is a countable support iteration of proper forcing notions of length $ \lt \omega_2$ and each forcing notion is forced to have size $ \le\omega_1$.

I can’t show $P$ forces $CH$. I tried to count the nice names for subsets of $\omega$,but I think the names are less than $|P|^{\omega\cdot |P|}=2^{\omega_1} $, it’s too large.

Please help me. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Proving this is not as simple as counting names unfortunately, see Theorem 2.12 in Abrahams article "Proper Forcing" in the handbook of set theory.

Comment: Thank you.I’m reading “set theory on the structure of the real line(Bartoszynski & Judah)” ,which says the lemma is an “easy result”.(p273,lemma 6.1.5, without proof) Is there an easier proof?

Comment: I do not know an easier proof, however in applications the iterands often satisfy Axiom A and in that case there is a simpler argument.

Comment: Thank you.I read the theorem 2.12 as you recommended, but I couldn’t understand the proof. I tried to compensate the omitted parts of the proof by following lemma 2.11,but it didn’t work because unlike the lemma 2.11, x(ξ) is not an ordinal.Could you help me to understand theorem 2.11?